# Making a floating text countdown work properly

Tags: lua, roblox

so I'm trying to make a floating text countdown from 30 to 0 and when it reaches 0 it says "Floor 1". The problem is the part of the script that makes it say Floor 1, the part that makes it count down from 30 works. I've identified the problem to be in line 17, it doesn't trigger when it should. Does anyone have an idea as to what might be causing it?

```
1- CountDownNumber = game.Workspace.Host["Floating Text"].LABEL
2- script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(HIT)
3-  local players = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(HIT.Parent)
4   local player = HIT.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
5   local attribute = game.StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts.number
6   if not player then return end
7   if attribute.Value == false then
8       attribute.Value = true 
9       CountDownNumber.Text = 30
10      for count= 29, 0, -1 do
11            
12          CountDownNumber.Text =CountDownNumber.Text -1
13          task.wait(1)
14          attribute.Value = false
15      end
16      while task.wait(0.3) do 
17              if CountDownNumber.Text.Value == 0 then
18               CountDownNumber.Text = "Floor_1"
19              
20              end
21          end 
22      
23      
24      end
25 end)
```

I tried adding loops to the if statement and changing it around but it still doesn't trigger when it should.

Comment: My guess would be that `CountDownNumber.Text.Value` returns a string, so would need to be `if CountDownNumber.Text.Value == "0"`

Comment: also are you sure `CountDownNumber.Text` has a Value property, I can't find any docs on this. Maybe link us to the docs for whatever type of object `.LABEL` is.

Comment: If CountDownNumber.Text.Value == "0" doesn't work either. if I know what a Value property is then I think it does have a Value property yes. .LABEL is a TextLabel.

Comment: Never mind it works, I just spoke too soon. Thank you!

Comment: Try `if CountDownNumber.Text == 0 then`.